# The existence of minimizer in Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $B\subset \mathbb R^2$ be a unit ball. let $v\in W^{1,2}(B)$ be given. We know that $0\leq v\leq 1$ and it is possible that $v=0$ on some positive $\mathcal L^2$ measurable set in $B$.

Let $w\in W^{1,2}(B)$ be given as well.

Define
$$
\bar u:=\operatorname{argmin}\left\{\int_B|\nabla u|^2v^2,\,u\in W^{1,2}(B),\,\, T[u]=T[w]\right\}
$$
where $T$ denote the standard trace operator.

My question: do we have $\bar u\in W^{1,2}(B)$ exist? (I do not care about uniqueness)

Comment: I got interested in your problem although I don't know that much about these things. First, the functional you want to minimize is convex and continuous (which you might already know). The set on which you would like to minimize it is a closed affine subspace, so it is convex, too, but not bounded though. So, none of the theorems in (what I found) http://users.ices.utexas.edu/~alen/articles/hilbert.pdf applies. But also if we let $T[w] = 0$ (so that the affine subspace turns to a linear one - and so to a Hilbert space itself) we cannot apply Corollary 5.6 because we cannot infer coercivity...

Comment: ... from Poincaré-Friedrichs due to the function $v$. Maybe you find generalized (weighted) Poincaré inequalities. Sorry that I couldn't help you solve the problem.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Thanks a lot for your comment sir. I will try to dig out some more about weighted space!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea, which I came up after @Svetoslav comment to my last answer. I think it can be improved to your case. Let $I=(0,1)$ and $v(x)=x$ for $x\in I$. Let $$W=\{u\in W^{1,2}(I):\ u(0)=1,\ u(1)=0\}.$$

Define $J$ by $$J(u)=\int x^2 |u'|^2.\ \forall\ u\in W.$$

Because $u$ is absolutely continuous and $u(0)=1$, $u(1)=0$, we must conclude that $u'$ is not equal to zero a.e., which implies that  $J(u)>0$.

I am gonna show that there is a sequence $u_k\in W$ such that $J(u_k)\to 0$. Indeed, let

$$ u_k(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    -kx+1       & \quad \text{if } x\in [0,1/k], \\
    0  & \quad \text{if } x\in [1/k,1].\\
  \end{cases}
$$

Note that $$J(u_k)=\int_0^{1/k} x^2k^2=\frac{1}{3k},$$

therefore $J(u_k)\to0$ if $k\to \infty$. We conclude that $J$ does not have a minimum in $W$.